# How to import node module passing subClass argument in ES6?

Tags: node.js, import, ecmascript-6, graphicsmagick

In JS I require in the node module gm (which I want to use with imageMagick rather than the default graphicsMagick) while passing an argument like this:

```
 var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
```

How can I do that in ES6?

```
import gm from "gm";
gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true });
```

doesn't work, because `gm` defaults to GraphicsMagick which isn't installed.

Comment: In your Node example, you save the return value of `subClass` into a variable. Do you do that in your ES6 code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @FelixKling: It defaults to graphicsMagick, which isn't installed and therefore logs `[Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "convert" "-size" "640x360" "xc:#f9b005" "-fill" "#ffffff" "-pointsize" "140" "-draw" "gravity center text 0,0 \"img\"" "/tmp/img.jpg" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found]`

Comment: Did you try to use the *return value* of `subClass`, just like you do in the first example? `const im = gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true }); /* use I'm here */`.

Comment: @FelixKling great! that works! thank u!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer from @Felix Kling works:

```
import gm from "gm";
const im = gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true });
```

...using `im` from here on!

Comment: I'm using gm in an AWS lambda (via Typescript/webpack). Seems to give runtime errors: `module initialization error: TypeError` - the compiled code is as such: `const gm_1 = __webpack_require__(17); const IMAGEMAGICK = gm_1.default.subClass({ imageMagick: true });`. Very weird, will keep investigating.

Comment: Removing the '.default.' fixed the above problem...not sure how to fix this properly though. `const IMAGEMAGICK = gm_1.subClass({ imageMagick: true });`

Comment: For those coming late, this fixed my problem in the above comments: `import * as GM from 'gm';`